# How are Mechanical Leg's "unused dice" counted with "You Choose, You Lose" rules?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

During the Robot's [bonus round](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Bonus_Round) I got a random rule which said "*Switch to "[You Choose, You Lose](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/You_Choose,_You_Lose)" rules*". This meant that I could select any dice I wanted, but equipment had a 50% chance of disappearing whenever I took a dice. During this run, I had the chance to buy Mechanical Leg which said "Do 2 damage for each unused dice".

When playing with "You Choose, You Lose" rules, does unused dice refer the dice values I haven't selected between 1-6, or is it the dice I've selected but haven't used on equipment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanical Leg only considers the dice in your tray as unused. Dice on the side that haven't been selected yet don't count.